# Normal iOS app size?

Tags: ios

I have an iOS app that weighs 10MBs when viewed on the App Store from an iPhone 6. The project contains 2.5MBs of images in total which should mean that more than 8MB of the app is code considering the 2x and 1x images would not have been downloaded on an iPhone 6. Is that normal for an app to have or is there something that can be done to further reduce the size of the app?

Comment: Uhhh.. Not sure how I put it.. An app with around 50 different classes maybe?

Comment: What I mean to ask is do we know how much is added to an app apart from the code and the images.

Comment: Your app size is well below the limits and have nothing to worry regarding the size.

Answer (score 1):

The [Apple App Distribution Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/UploadingYourApptoiTunesConnect/UploadingYourApptoiTunesConnect.html) covers some of what goes on here. You are compiling for several different platforms (if you only target iOS, then you have several possible processor targets), and more if you include watchOS and / or tvOS.

If you are writing in Swift, your apps may be larger because it includes libraries in the build.

You may also be able to remove debug symbols, which can reduce your app size.

Ultimately, there is a lot more in that ipa file then just a few images and class files.

Comment: Is there anything that can be done regarding the architectures the app supports? My app currently has 'Standard Architectures' set in the Architectures in Build Settings.